# asp.net...How Can I Still See Available Classes When Bundling?

Tags: asp.net, bundle

I'm developing in asp.net using Master/content pages.  I'm using Bundling by adding it to the Master page. I think I have everything set up correctly; however, when I'm developing I can no longer see my list of available classes on the content pages if I'm trying to set up html......without bundling a list of classes used to pop up when I'd get to the class= part; but with bundling nothing appears.

My setup looks like this, in the Master page I'm referencing the bundles:

```
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title><%: Page.Title %> - JCPS DMC</title>

    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" />

    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder2" runat="server">
        <%: Styles.Render("~/bundles/bootstrapCSS", "~/bundles/utilitiesCSS") %>
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/utilitiesJs", "~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="contentHeader" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

And my BundleConfig.cs file looks like this:

```
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace DMC
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on Bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254726
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/WebFormsJs").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js",
                  "~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js",
                  "~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js",
                  "~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js",
                  "~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js",
                  "~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js",
                  "~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js",
                  "~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/MsAjaxJs").Include(
                "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjax.js",
                "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxApplicationServices.js",
                "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxTimer.js",
                "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/utilitiesJs").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                "~/Scripts/common.js",
                "~/Scripts/analytics.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/highCharts").Include(
                "~/Scripts/highcharts/4.2.0/highcharts.js",
                "~/Scripts/highcharts/4.2.0/highcharts-more.js",
                "~/Scripts/highcharts/4.2.0/highcharts-3d.js",
                "~/Scripts/highcharts/4.2.0/modules/broken-axis.js",
                "~/Scripts/highcharts/4.2.0/modules/data.js",
                "~/Scripts/highcharts/4.2.0/modules/drilldown.js",
                "~/Scripts/highcharts/4.2.0/modules/exporting.js",
                "~/Scripts/highcharts/4.2.0/modules/funnel.js",
                "~/Scripts/highcharts/4.2.0/modules/heatmap.js",
                "~/Scripts/highcharts/4.2.0/modules/no-data-to-display.js",
                "~/Scripts/highcharts/4.2.0/modules/offline-exporting.js",
                "~/Scripts/highcharts/4.2.0/modules/solid-gauge.js",
                "~/Scripts/highcharts/4.2.0/modules/treemap.js",
                "~/Scripts/highcharts/4.2.0/adapters/standalone-framework.js"
                ));

            // Use the Development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you’re
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/bootstrapCSS").Include(
                "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                "~/Content/bootstrap-multiselect.css",
                "~/Content/bootstrap-navbar.css",
                "~/Content/bootstrap-overrides.css"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/utilitiesCSS").Include(
                "~/Content/print.css",
                "~/Content/common.css",
                "~/Content/site.css",
                "~/Content/colorThemes.css"));

            BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
        }
    }
}
```

That last line in the BundleConfig.cs file I thought was the key to debugging:

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false
```

I thought that if it was set to false, it overrode the web.config file and allowed you to see classnames...is this incorrect? Am I missing something else?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation for the property: [BundleTable.EnableOptimizations Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.bundletable.enableoptimizations(v=vs.110).aspx). Enabling it will bundle and minify your scripts/css files, see [Bundling and Minification](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification) for complete details. This provides for faster load times for your clients as there is less that is transmitted over the wire (less white space, line breaks etc). It makes client side script debugging more difficult because your whole script could be on a single line and your variable names in javascript are usually also shortened. It has nothing to do with server side code or the web.config.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, would you happen to know the second part of my question..why IntelliSense doesn't show my class names that are being bundled?

Answer (score 0):

No. You are not missing anything. According to MSDN you can also use,

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
    <!-- Lines removed for clarity. -->
</system.web>
```

Documentation clearly says that,

> Unless EnableOptimizations is true or the debug attribute in the
>   compilation Element  in the Web.config file is set to false, files
>   will not be bundled or minified.

Link: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification

Comment: Same for you Sir, thanks for confirming, would you happen to know the second part of my question..why IntelliSense doesn't show my class names that are being bundled?